# Hyperledger Composer Error: instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am running Hyperledger composer on two local machines 
I am able to connect them successfully but I am getting below errors.

AS I am trying to upgrade network.

```
composer network upgrade -c org1@fund-clearing-network -n fund-clearing-network -V 0.2.7-deploy.0

Upgrading business network fund-clearing-network to version 0.2.7-deploy.0
```

✖ Upgrading business network definition. This may take a minute...

**Error:**

> Error trying to upgrade business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upgrade the network definition you must use peer admin card not the network admin card.